# How to call and set value from another activity to my activity?

Tags: android, xml, populate

I have an activity called "PurcahseActivity" and the value of user's transactions is displayed there. "TOTAL: € 1138.50" in the attached picture.
The value is generated after a user has made a purchase. 
[image]

I have another activity called "SalesReportActivity" and here, I need to display the same value in this layout.

[image]

What is the best way to achieve this?

This is my PurchaseLayout.xml.  'net_total' is the ID of the value displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/net_total_value"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/net_total"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey_standard_text"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

I have researched a lot but couldn't find any solution for this specific question. Basically, i just want to display the same value in my salesReport.

Comment: these two are separate activities?

Comment: How do you navigate from first activity to the second? Is it after a 'Pusrchase' button click or something like that?

Comment: Yes, they are two separate activities. When the user clicks the "purchase" button, the final amount is displayed. In the report activity, only the product name is shown and I want to display the Total value as well.

Comment: You can also archive this by using `onActivityResult()` and `setResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this:

1. In PurcahseActivity, after a user has made a purchase, save this value to sharedPreferences.

   ```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat("total", value).apply();
   ```
2. In SalesReportActivity load this value:

   ```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   float value = sharedPreferences.getFloat("total", 0f);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways that I know of, which can help you:

- If you're starting the second activity after the first one, you can
  use `Intent.putExtra` and retrieve that value in the second activity
- If that value is going to be reused in more than 1 place, it would
  make sense to actually save it in `SharedPreferences` and then fetch
  it wherever needed
- If you want to asynchronously get and send that value between any two components but you have no desire of saving it, you can use a great library called [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

> I had not given you any code, since each of these 3 methods is well-known and many times explained. You can always find out on your own how to use `SharedPreferences` and `Intents`. As far as the `EventBus` goes, it has great documentation, but if you still had any trouble using it, feel free to ping me or write a question here.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of passing information through activity is using Intent when starting the activity. In the source activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("YOUR_FLAG", yourValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in your TargetActivity, e.g. in the onCreate(...)

```
float yourValue;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    yourValue = extras.getFloat("YOUR_FLAG");
}
```

To persist your data across more than 2 activities, then use SharedPreferences. There are other approaches like Database, File, or even EventBus, if a more complex solution is required.